# Описание стилей в разметке или в отдельном файле?

Tags: css

Где лучше всего описывать стили и почему: в отдельном файле, теге `<style></style>`, или внутри какого либо тега в атрибуте `style=""` ?

И насколько плохо если я основную часть буду описывать в атрибуте `style=""` и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше, конечно, в отдельном файле. Однако в отдельном файле стили будут иметь приоритет ниже чем в в теге <style></style> или атрибуте style="".

*И насколько плохо если я основную часть буду описывать в атрибуте style="" и почему?*

ОЧЕНЬ ПЛОХО! Замучаетесь потом править стили, если потребуется.

Comment: Это страшно только моими мучениями и всё ? А на скорость загрузки страниц это не влияет ?

Comment: Лишнее обращение к серверу за файлом стилей это лишний запрос, который, конечно, сказывается на скорости загрузки страницы, но если запросов не много, то это не сильно заметно. Однако, если Вы так заботитесь о скорости загрузки, то используйте <style></style>. Так Вы убиваете двух зайцев: уменьшаете количество обращений к серверу и позволяете себе гибко менять свойства стилей в одном месте. Лучше только в самых критичный случаях использовать для стилей атрибут style="".

Answer (score 1):

Я бы стал применять:

1. `<style type="text/css">...</style>`: следует применять когда надо динамически менять стили. Например:

   `<? if(date('w')==6){
       $color = 'red';
   } else {
       $color = 'black';
   } ?>`
2. В отдельном `CSS`-файле: когда содержимое `css`-файла не меняется динамически; также оно кешируется и не нагружает лишний раз `PHP`, `PERL`, `NodeJS` (или что у вас на сервере :)))
3. В теге `style="..."` -- то же, что и в п. 1.